# Reset offset animation on draggable item in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, drag, android-jetpack-compose

I have a green square that I can drag vertically. But whenever I stop dragging it, I want it to reset the offset to the start with an animation. I tried it like this, but I can't figure it out. Does someone know how to do it?

```
@Composable
fun DraggableSquare() {
    var currentOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(0F) }
    val resetAnimation by animateIntOffsetAsState(targetValue = IntOffset(0, currentOffset.roundToInt()))

    var shouldReset = false

    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Surface(
            color = Color(0xFF34AB52),
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .offset {
                    when {
                        shouldReset -> resetAnimation
                        else -> IntOffset(0, currentOffset.roundToInt())
                    }
                }
                .draggable(
                    state = rememberDraggableState { delta -> currentOffset += delta },
                    orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                    onDragStopped = {
                        shouldReset = true
                        currentOffset = 0F
                    }
                )
        ) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can define the offset as an [`Animatable`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatable).
While dragging use the method `snapTo` to update the current value as the initial value and the `onDragStopped` to start the animation.

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val offsetY  =  remember { Animatable(0f) }

Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    Surface(
        color = Color(0xFF34AB52),
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .offset {
                IntOffset(0, offsetY.value.roundToInt())
            }
            .draggable(
                state = rememberDraggableState { delta ->
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        offsetY.snapTo(offsetY.value + delta)
                    }
                },
                orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
                onDragStopped = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        offsetY.animateTo(
                            targetValue = 0f,
                            animationSpec = tween(
                                durationMillis = 3000,
                                delayMillis = 0
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
    ) {
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, this fixes the reset part, but I also want the reset to happen with a smooth animation. Is that possible?

Comment: @DonnyRozendal I've updated the answer to add the animation.

Comment: You sir are a true hero, thank you! Really clean and readable. My other solution involves multiple states that created race conditions, so putting everything in one Animatable is the way to go. I had this idea as well, but didn't want to animate the dragging. But I see that you solved that with `snapTo`, which is genius.

Comment: Also, inside the `snapTo` function, it should say offsetY and not offsetX. But I can't request an edit since it's not enough characters.

Comment: Please explain to me why the `Coroutine Scope` is necessary here ?

Comment: @Ir058 both `snapTo` and `animateTo` are suspend functions, the scope is needed to call them